# Sound doesn't come back after hibernation

Tags: arch-linux, audio, pulseaudio, alsa, acpi

I tried to debug it myself and had some success, but still need some advice in order to solve the problem properly.

**The Problem**: After I put my computer to hibernation I have no sound (suspend works fine).

**My system**: HP spectre X360 4100 - Broadwell

**The error message**: dmesg shows `rt286 i2c-INT343A:00: I2C error -110`

**The partial solution**

If I go to pavucontrol, switch to headset and then back to builtin speakers I get the sound back, but it's too loud, I have to open alsamixer, choose the card and lower the volume on master. That will bring the sound back to normal.

**The Questions**

- Does anyone have an idea why this is happening based on the error
  message or the "solution"?
- Does anyone have a way to automate the "solution"?
- Any other insights?

I'd be happy to supply any additional necessary info...

---

**Bonus:**
If I set `acpi_osi='!Windows 2013' acpi_osi='!Windows 2012'` on grub, the sound works, and keep working even after hibernation but then there is a problem with the accelerometer, and `monitor-sensor` reports it as "undefined". 
When I do that aplay gives different output for the card:
`card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3242 Analog [ALC3242 Analog]`
might be a different approach to solving the problem, but I don't know enough about ACPI...
normal output from `aplay -l`:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: broadwellrt286 [broadwell-rt286], device 0: System Playback/Capture (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: broadwellrt286 [broadwell-rt286], device 1: Offload0 Playback (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: broadwellrt286 [broadwell-rt286], device 2: Offload1 Playback (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```